# jQuery Cycle Not Resuming

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have got the jquery cycle plugin and have been asked to pause it on mouse hover. Unfortunately, I have a transparent image hovering over the entire slideshow (it's a link - click anywhere on slideshow and off you go somewhere else) so I have set up the following code:

```
  jQuery("#holder").mouseenter(
    function(){
      jQuery("ul.cycle").cycle("pause");
    }
  ).mouseleave(
    function(){
      jQuery("ul.cycle").cycle("resume");
    }
  );
```

While this works if I am hovering for a short moment, if I hover for more than the timeout period specified in my constructor then the system does not restart.

I have browsed SO and came across  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316988/jquery-cycle-plugin-stop-sliding-after-switching-to-another-tab) post:

> The reason why this problem has been occuring was that next iteration
>   where transition suppose to occure was setup before completion of
>   previous transition. In some cases, next transition was fired before
>   the previous has finished, at the beginning of that new transition
>   there's a check whenever there's already other animation going on - if
>   so, the function would just return and stop (without setting up next
>   iteration). After the ongoing animation was finished, the slideshow
>   was stopped, because there was no next transition scheduled.

How do I get cycle to restart the timer for the current slide after I have used 'pause'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the fix supplied by @WTK at github: https://github.com/WTK/cycle